# simple database edit webpage recommendations

Tags: php, database

It's been a long time since I've made something like this, I'm just wondering if I'm not re-inventing the wheel.

My client currently has a bunch of data in an excel file and wants this to be on the web for various reasons (needs to be able to edit it from pretty much anywhere, multiple users, etc...). Also needs to be able to generate reports and some custom functionality.

I'm planning to build this from scratch in PHP, but are there any building blocks I can use? Something that already has a way of (nicely) listing table entries and editing them etc... would be a good start.

Comment: In addition of the question being too board it is also considered off topic as requesting alternatives, software, services and resources are off topic. To avoid further disappointment please visit our [Help Center](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked that Google Spreadsheets doesn't already do what you want?

It would certainly allow a spreadsheet to be edited from anywhere and by multiple users.

You may also be able to use their api to extend what it is being used for.

Comment: I totally see your point, but I can't sell a Google Spreadsheet... (it's client work), and I also understand why they want to keep their stuff independent. It does not need to be that robust at all, the chance that two people will edit the same record before a page refreshes is nearly impossible.

Comment: In that case, I'd probably look into the open source spreadsheets before starting from scratch.  A quick Google threw this one up - http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxSpreadsheet/